# Unity 3D Character Controller.move forward strangely at certain rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a custom 3 Person Controller.
I'm using a Character Controller, so I translate my "Player", with his Character Controller.
Like that :

```
_ownController.Move(transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
```

I want the Player to go forward depending of his rotation.
When I did this with Player.Translate() it works perfectly well, since I changed to this It's not working at all, but I need physics on my Player :(

Please, help me I'm going to be desperate, it's like a couple hours I'm stuck on that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this for your `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)` to find your forward direction.
Because transform.forward gives forward direction, specifically 'blue axis' direction in world space. Whereas, `transform.TransformDirection`, gives direction in local space